# Approximation in Bochner spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

Is there any result like the [Bramble-Hilbert lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bramble%E2%80%93Hilbert_lemma) for Bochner spaces?

More specifically:  let $H$ be a (e.g.) Hilbert space, $I\subset \mathbb R$ a bounded interval, and $L \in \mathcal L(H^k(I;H), Y)$ for $Y$ a normed space. If $L$ vanishes on $k-1$ polynomials, do we necessarily have $||L v ||_Y\leq C_k ||\partial_t^{k} v||_{L^2(I,H)}$?

Comment: Writing $v(t)=p(t)+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\int_0^t (t-s)^{k-1}v^{(k)}(s)\, ds$, with $p$ the Taylor polynomial at $0$ of order $k-1$, then $\|v-p\|_{H^k} \leq C\|v^{(k)}\|_{L^2}$. Then $\|Lv\|=\|L(v-p)\| \leq \|L\|\|v-p\|_{H^k} \leq \|L\| \|v^{(k)}\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I will accept your comment as the answer, if you convert it to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $$v(t)=p(t)+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\int_0^t (t-s)^{k-1}v^{(k)}(s)\, ds$$ with $p$ the Taylor polynomial at $0$ of degree $k-1$, then $\|v-p\|_{H^k} \leq C\|v^{(k)}\|_{L^2}$. It follows that
$$\|Lv\|=\|L(v-p)\| \leq \|L\|\|v-p\|_{H^k} \leq C\|L\|\|v^{(k)}\|_{L^2}.
$$